# ActionListener not doing anything on button click

Tags: java, swing, jtable, actionlistener

```
public class ReadGameDetailsWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private GameFactory theFactory = GameFactory.getInstance();
    private HashMap<String, Game> theListOfGames = theFactory.listOfGames();

    JTable table;

    // Delete game panel
            JPanel deletePanel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2,2));
            JLabel theDeleteGameName = new JLabel("Game Name:");
            JTextField theDeleteGameNameField = new JTextField();
            JButton theDeleteCancelButton = new JButton("Clear");
            JButton theDeleteOKButton = new JButton("Delete");

    String[] columns = {"Name", "Developer", "Genre", "Rating"};
    Object[][] tableData = new Object[theListOfGames.keySet().size()][4];

    public void fillDetails() {
        int index = 0;
        for (String key : theListOfGames.keySet())
        {
            Game game = theListOfGames.get(key);
            tableData[index][0] = game.getName();
            tableData[index][1] = game.getDeveloper();
            tableData[index][2] = game.getGenre();
            tableData[index][3] = game.getOutOfTen() + "/10";
            index++;
        }
    }

    public ReadGameDetailsWindow() {
        fillDetails();

        deletePanel.add(theDeleteGameName);
        deletePanel.add(theDeleteGameNameField);
        deletePanel.add(theDeleteCancelButton);
        deletePanel.add(theDeleteOKButton);

        TitledBorder deleteBorder = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Delete Section");

        table = new JTable(tableData, columns);
        table.setPreferredScrollableViewportSize(new Dimension(500, 50));
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(table);

        JPanel controls = new JPanel();
        controls.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,3));

        controls.add(deletePanel);

        setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));

        getContentPane().add(scrollPane);
        getContentPane().add(controls);
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800,800);


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource().equals(theDeleteOKButton)) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Delete Button Pressed");
                String aGameName = theDeleteGameNameField.getText();
                theFactory.deleteGame(aGameName);
                fillDetails();
                table.repaint();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(new JFrame(), aGameName + " has been deleted!");
            } catch (Exception aException) {
                aException.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, effectively, nothing is happening when I click on my theDeleteOKButton.  I'm trying to delete a record from my HashMap, the one where information is displayed from.

I have tried creating and instantiating the buttons inside and outside the main constructor and have attempted to add actionListeners individually but I can't seem to get a reaction at all.

Do I need to move the buttons or is there an alternative way that I am missing?
Sorry I am pretty new to Swing and just trying to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add action listener to your buttons. do this:

```
theDeleteCancelButton.addActionListener(this); //detects button press action for theDeleteCancelButton
theDeleteOKButton.addActionListener(this); //detects button press action for theDeleteOKButton
```